# Stepped Stacked chart not seen as EmbeddedChart in Google sheets API?

Tags: charts, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am working with a spreadsheet that contains multiple sheets. In every sheet there is 1 chart.

I am using Google Apps Script to get these specific charts, which is working perfectly for all types of charts, except for the 'Stepped Stacked Chart', not to confuse with the 'Stepped Chart'.

Example code to explain the issue:

```
function getCharts(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var steppedStackedSheet = ss.getSheetByName('chart_2');
var otherChart = ss.getSheetByName('chart_1');

Logger.log(steppedStackedSheet.getCharts()); // returns an empty array
Logger.log(otherChart.getCharts()); // returns an array [EmbeddedChart] - This is what i also expect to see in the steppedStackedSheet chart.
}
```

I am buidling a script that downloads the chart as an image, but it's strange that this specific chart is not being recognized as a chart.

Haven't found anything on Google but hopefully someone here has had a similar issue and/or a solution.

[Here an example sheet, also including the script](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X309KloHyAuhEAvWJmmJrV2P20_R61vLIvAAMxbcjAY/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As described in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/steppedareachart#stacked-stepped-area-charts),

> For 100% stacking, the stacks of elements at each domain-value are rescaled such that they add up to 100%. The options for this are `isStacked: 'percent'`, which formats each value as a percentage of 100%, and `isStacked: 'relative'`, which formats each value as a fraction of 1. There is also an `isStacked: 'absolute'` option, which is functionally equivalent to `isStacked: true`.

You may use [`setStacked()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-column-chart-builder#setstacked) which uses stacked lines, meaning that line and bar values are stacked (accumulated). By default, there is no stacking. The return type is [`EmbeddedColumnChartBuilder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-column-chart-builder#).

Comment: Hi abilita, thank you for responding but I am not looking to build a chart. The chart has already been built and is in a sheet. I purely want to get the chart as a Blob so I can transform it into an image. For all other charts this is done by sheet.getCharts()[0].getBlob(), this just doesnt work for the stepped stacked area chart. I will create a sample sheet today to share with this post later this evening

Comment: I have added a sample sheet including the code in my post.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X309KloHyAuhEAvWJmmJrV2P20_R61vLIvAAMxbcjAY/edit?usp=sharing